# How to save context after importing data using MagicalImport?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1

I imported a json array using MagicalImport (version 2.1) MR_importFromArray method. I am trying to retrieve the imported NSManagedObjects using MR_findAll without any success. Here're the variations that I have tried so far:

```
//Attempt 1
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
  [Thread MR_importFromArray:threadsData];
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
  NSArray *allThreads = [Thread MR_findAll];
}];

//Attempt 2
[MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
  [Thread MR_importFromArray:threadsData inContext:localContext];
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
  NSArray *allThreads = [Thread MR_findAllInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]];
}];

//Attempt 3
NSManagedObjectContext *context =[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
 [Thread MR_importFromArray:threadsData inContext:context];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
NSArray *allThreads = [Thread MR_findAllInContext:context];

//Attempt 4
[Thread MR_importFromArray:threadsData];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
NSArray *allThreads = [Thread MR_findAll];
```

And here's the error that I  see in console :

```
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0xb2566e0) NO CHANGES IN ** DEFAULT ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Seems like there's a bug in MR_importFromArray. When I manually iterate over the objects and save them to the context, it works fine. Here's how :

```
[MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
  [threadsData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [Thread MR_importFromObject:obj];
  }];
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
  NSArray *allThreads = [Thread MR_findAll];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```